# Check- in & check-out files using client object model

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

As the title says, how can I Check- in &  check-out files using client object model?

Comment: Hi! Can you please add a tag indicating the version of SharePoint? 2007, 2010 or 2013?

Comment: sharePoint version  2010

Answer (score 10):

To check-out:

```
//get the connection
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sitename");

//get the home page
File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/SitePages/home.aspx");
ctx.load(home);
//check whether file is already checkout. If not then only do the checkout. 
if (home.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
{
   home.CheckOut();
}
```

To check-in:

```
//Only checkin if the file is already checkout. 
if (home.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
   home.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on it's own.  Do we have to call like `ctx.Execute()` or something afterwards?

Comment: Turns out the check-in is not performed until call `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` -- further, if the file is not checked out, this will totally throw an exception when you call `ctx.ExecuteQuery();`.

Comment: Additionally the `file.CheckOut()` call will cause an exception to be thrown on the next `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` if the file is already checked out to you.