# How to check out files in a document library using SharePoint(On-Premise) 2013 REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server

I have files in a document library which needs to be checkout by some automatic scripts from other web application(Asp.net/javascript) using SharePoint REST API. I'm working on Sharepoint Server 2013 On Premise

I found that we can achieve it only in

1. Sharepoint Apps
2. SharePoint Server Project

I gone through this links

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx#ClientAPIs
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Is it Possible?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You don't know REST endpoint for check-out, or how to make REST call between two web applications?

Comment: How to make SharePoint REST API call from other application(Not in SP Web application). Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

APP

```
'use strict';  
var hostweburl;   
var appweburl;   

    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is   
    // needed to use the SharePoint object model  
    $(document).ready(function () {  

            //Get the URI decoded URLs.   
    hostweburl =   
        decodeURIComponent(   
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));   
    appweburl =   
        decodeURIComponent(   
            getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));   
               // Resources are in URLs in the form:  
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource  
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";    

        // Load the js file and continue to load the page with information about the list top level folders.  
        // SP.RequestExecutor.js to make cross-domain requests  

         // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler  
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);  
             });  

             // Function to prepare and issue the request to get  
          //  SharePoint data  
          function execCrossDomainRequest() {  
            // executor: The RequestExecutor object  
            // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.  
            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);             

            var metatdata = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListListItem' }, 'Title': 'changelistitemtitle'}";  

            // Issue the call against the app web.  
            // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:  
            //      appweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items  
            // The response formats the data in the JSON format.  
            // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the  
            //      sucess and error events respectively.  
            executor.executeAsync(  
                {            
          url:    
            appweburl +    
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/ GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(  
  '/Shared Documents/a.txt')/CheckOut()?@target='" +    
            hostweburl + "'",    
        method: "POST",    
        body: metatdata ,    
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose", "content-length": metatdata.length, "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE", "IF-MATCH": "*" },            
            success: function (data) {  
                alert("success: " + JSON.stringify(data));  
            },  
            error: function (err) {  
                alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));  
            }    
                }            
            );                

          }                    
    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get   
    // the current users information        
//Utilities   

// Retrieve a query string value.   
// For production purposes you may want to use   
// a library to handle the query string.   
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {   
    var params =   
        document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");     
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {   
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");   
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)   
            return singleParam[1];   
    }   
}
```

source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/check-out-files-in-sharepoint-library-2013-using-rest-api/

JS

```
 function CheckOutFile() {
             var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();           
                 var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                 this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");
                 this.item = list.getItemById(1);
                 this.file = this.item.get_file();
                 this.file.checkOut();
                 clientContext.load(this.file)
                 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));           
         }
```

source: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Checkin-and-CheckOut-in-SharePoint-2013-using-Javascript

CSOM

```
//get the connection
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sitename");

//get the home page
File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/SitePages/home.aspx");

//checkout
home.CheckOut();
```

source: [Check- in & check-out files using client object model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84301/check-in-check-out-files-using-client-object-model)

Comment: what will be hostweburl & appweburl

Comment: When the App first launches, SharePoint provides three values in the query string named: SPHostUrl, SPAppWebUrl and SPLanguage.

Comment: I don't want in Sharepoint App, can I run above script in basic html with javascript ?

Comment: you can use apps, CSOM, JS, C#, just choose your flavor

Comment: if you want to run automatic scripts form an external location, I would recommend a c# console application using the client object model

Comment: how can I achieve with REST API as you shown is in JS where I need to include SP library's correct me If I'm wrong..

Comment: I don't think you can use the REST API outside of sharepoint without using apps. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134300/updating-sharepoint-item-using-rest-api-from-outside-of-sharepoint